# VS Code API extension development - configuration points issue

Tags: json, typescript, api, visual-studio-code, configuration

This is from `package.json` file:

```
"configuration": [
            {
                "id": "projectmanager",
                "title": "Enable or Disable project manager",
                "order": 1,
                "properties": {
                    "AIO.projectmanager": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "order": 1,
                        "description": "Enabled - true, Disabled - false : for Project manager."
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I debug and run it, the setting does not show up in a GUI nor in the settings.json of the extension development host.

Any way to fix this?

Edit: When i run the extension, it sends a notification saying "[my:\extension\workspace]: property `engines` is mandatory and must be of type `object` "

Comment: I assume that is within the `"contributes": {...}` key?  I don't know if it makes any difference because I use `"configuration": [...]` (an array) whereas the examples in the docs use an object instead `"configuration": {...}`.  Finally, I would add a `scope` just  as an easy try.  I know it has a default value but see if it changes anything.

Comment: what should i add in the scope?
edit: nope its not working , dear Mark.

Comment: And you do have ` "name": "aio",` in your `package.json`?   And ` "engines": {
  "vscode": "^1.56.0"
 },`  Some minimum version of vscode necessary.

Comment: yes i do - mark

Comment: if you name the property `AIO.enableProjectmanager` there is no need for the description and title can be simplified